# Edit configurations of Android emulator's (AVD) Build.FINGERPRINT

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My avd returns following fingerprint

```
google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emulator64_x86_64_arm64:12/SE1A.211212.001.B1/8023802:user/release-keys
```

and My real device returns following fingerprint

```
samsung/m21nnxx/m21:12/SP1A.210812.016/M215FXXU2CVCC:user/release-keys
```

I found that this is as per the following structure.

```
$(BRAND)/$(PRODUCT)/$(DEVICE)/$(BOARD):$(VERSION.RELEASE)/$(ID)/$(VERSION.INCREMENTAL):$(TYPE)/$(TAGS)
```

Is there a way for us to modify these details for AVD to match with the device like device name, brand etc.